# creating a mobile and desktop website

Tags: html, css, redirect, mobile, directory

I want to know is that to create a mobile and desktop wesbite you have to create to different websites like this for example:

C:/users/harry/desktop/desktopurlname/...

and

C:/users/harry/desktop/mobileurlname/...

or do you have to put them together in one website folder root and either use meida querys in the html/css files or create another copy of the same html file and make one desktop html file and a mobile html file.
i am only asking because i am confused about how to do mobile and desktop redirect by code and how to do it by folder roots as well.
can you please tell how it works please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some sites don't create a version to both, mobile and desktop, if you use media queries is the enough. You are confusing because you see sites like this: http://marcelo.com/mobile and the same site like this http://marcelo.com/desktop.
As I sayed you can create a site to each media, but the best, on my opinio it's create one and so, make the media queries.

**EDIT**
the site is the same on above, but the uri `/mobile` says to PHP (example) like this:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['media'] == 'mobile') {
    //...loads the css to mobile
} elseif ($_GET['media'] == 'desktop') {
    //...loads the css to desktop
}
```

the `$_GET` here its just a example

Comment: So you are saying is that just create one website and use media queries in the html files and don't worry about the redirects the only use the rdirect for the css file to load on to the website for mobile and desktop site.... Oh i get it now. Thanks for your help now my brain is not confused as it was before. :D Thanks

Comment: Yes, if you knows PHP can use some code like above, sorry for my beginner english. But I think that you can understand me. @HarrySmart

Comment: It's ok i was able to understand what you said. You don't need to be sorry :D